# Is it possible for absolute div to have width: auto, and also ignore it's parent's width?

Tags: css, width, css-position

I'm trying to make a `div` that stretches to fit its content, up to some maximum width, after which the content should wrap.

Using an absolutely positioned `div` works fine -- unless its parent's width is limited. When its parent's width is limited, the absolutely positioned `div` acts as though its `max-width` is the `width` of its parent.

I'd essentially like for the absolutely positioned `div` to "pretend" its parent has 100% width, and give me the nice "stretch-to-fit" behavior, while honoring the `max-width` I set on it.

In the below example, I'd like the first `.abs` to work, even though it is a child of a "skinny" div.

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  background: #EEE;
  width: 100px;
}
.abs {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 200px;
  /* width:  auto, but ignore parent! */
}

.parent2 {
  margin-top: 150px;
  background: rgba(0,128,0,.1);
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="parent">
    <div>
      Doesn't work.
    </div>
    <div class="abs">
      This wraps after 100px, because it's parent has 100px width.
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="parent2">
    <div>
      Does work.
    </div>
    <div class="abs">
      This wraps at 200px, because it's parent is as wide as the viewport, so it honors the max-width of 200px.
    </div>
  </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nqws2p09/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is *somewhat* solved by wrapping `abs` in an absolute div that has a much wider width than the `relative` parent.  The problem now becomes sizing `wrapper` to stretch to the right of the viewport, which is a topic for another question.

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  background: #EEE content-box; /* Color only the content */
  width: 100px;
}
.abs-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 800px;
}
.abs {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
  <div class="parent">
    <div>
      Doesn't work.
    </div>
    <div class="abs-wrapper">
      <div class="abs">
        This correctly wraps after 200px, because it's parent is a wrapper with a very large width. Thus, this div will stretch-to-fit, and also honor max-width.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  
    <div class="parent" style="margin-top: 150px">
    <div>
      Doesn't work.
    </div>
    <div class="abs-wrapper">
      <div class="abs">
        &lt; 200px shrinks to fit.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rxwqtpsz/

Comment: in this case simply make the new wrapper to have 200px and you can remove the max-width, it's not more needed. And also remove absolute from the inner div and use inline-block

Answer (score 6):

Use `width: max-content;` to force the absolutely positioned child to size itself based on its content instead of the parent element's dimensions.

This also works alongside max-width.

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  background: #EEE;
  width: 100px;
}
.abs {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 200px;
  width: max-content; /* this forces width: auto */
}
```

```html
  <div class="parent">
    <div>
      Div inside parent element. This will wrap at 100px.
    </div>
    <div class="abs">
      This absolutely positioned child element wraps after 200px, even though the parent's max-width is set to 100px
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since padding of the parent is considered in the width calculation of the absolute element you can then add more padding to the parent element:

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  background: #EEE content-box; /* Color only the content */
  width: 100px;
  padding-right:200px;
  margin-right:-200px; /*to consume the padding added*/
}
.abs {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 200px;
}

.parent2 {
  margin-top: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div>
      Does work.
    </div>
    <div class="abs">
      This wraps after 100px, because it's parent has 100px width.
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="parent parent2">
    <div>
      Does work.
    </div>
    <div class="abs">
      This wraps at 200px, because it's parent is as wide as the viewport, so it honors the max-width of 200px.
    </div>
  </div>
```

Or consider a big margin on the positioned element:

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  background: #EEE;
  width: 100px;
}
.abs {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 200px;
  margin-right:-200px;
}

.parent2 {
  margin-top: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div>
      Does work.
    </div>
    <div class="abs">
      This wraps after 100px, because it's parent has 100px width.
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="parent parent2">
    <div>
      Does work.
    </div>
    <div class="abs">
      This wraps at 200px, because it's parent is as wide as the viewport, so it honors the max-width of 200px.
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: This causes "parent" to take up 300px of width, when it should only take up 100px.

Comment: @JS_Riddler that's why I added the negative margin to consume the extra space taking and since it's padding, the content inside will still take 100px

Comment: I checked by adding a border and saw it was 300px wide -- but you are right, the `flow` is correct. However, now it becomes an issue to add styling like `background` and `border`. I posted a solution which seems to me to work better, let me know what you think.

Comment: @JS_Riddler added another idea to this if intrested